# grails userHome variable

Tags: grails, configuration, home-directory

I need, in Config.groovy, the $userHome variable.
It works in my development machine, infact I use the following:

```
environments {
   development {
           grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = 
                   "${userHome}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
            ...
    } 
   production {
           grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = 
                   "${userHome}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
            ...
    } 
}
```

or

```
 environments {
   development {
       grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir =
             "${System.properties.'user.home'}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
        ...
       }
  production {
       grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir =
             "${System.properties.'user.home'}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"
        ...
       }
 }
```

In my production machine, it seems that $userHome is `usr/share/tomcat7` and not the correct Home path.
Why do I have this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably *is* the correct behaviour - it looks like your production Tomcat is running as a specific system user (probably called tomcat7 or similar) whose home directory is `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

If you want to set up different values for a configuration option for the development and production systems, the standard way to do that is to use the [`environments` mechanism](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments)

```
// standard value
grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = "${userHome}/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"    

environments {
  production {
    // override the value for the production environment
    grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = "/data/docm_patients_doc/{patientcf}/"    
  }
}
```

Now in development mode it will use the standard path involving `${userHome}` but when running in production mode (when you build a `grails prod war` and deploy it to tomcat) it will use the setting from inside the `environments` block.  You can likewise have a `development` block inside `environments` for settings that apply only in development mode.

Note that `Config.groovy` is parsed from top to bottom, so the generic settings must be ahead of the environment-specific ones.

Comment: how can I change it to let the userHome be like in production machine? Or how can I get in Grails Config.groovy file the home directory of the machine?

Comment: @FrancescoDS `userHome` _is_ the home directory of whichever user ID Tomcat is running under.  It sounds like what you really need is a way to configure a different directory in production mode _instead of_ using `userHome`.  Generally I do this either by hardcoding the production path in my `production` environments block or by basing it off the working directory of the Tomcat process rather than the home of the tomcat user, and put an appropriate `cd` in the startup script to control what that current directory will be.

Comment: how do you hardcode the production path in production block? Can you give me some code example?

Comment: @FrancescoDS it's just the standard [environments mechanism](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) as described in the user guide.

Comment: I've read it, but I don't understand what do you mean...In my config.groovy I have environments section, with production and development subsection. In there I use the $userHome to link a path, but I don't know how to change it to have the result expected...I do some edit in my post to show the content of Config.groovy...I hope you can give me some other suggestion :)

Comment: @FrancescoDS all I'm suggesting is that you use a hard-coded path in the `production` version _instead of_ using `$userHome`